# Unable to center align the label field of form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to center align my form w.r.t. page, but if i use the following, only text input field is getting aligned but label remains at left. How to resolve it?

```
<div id="passCode"></div>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend style="color:#145FAC">Please Fill in the Online Form</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control formWidth" id="inputName" placeholder="Nam" />
            </div>...</div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: Adding updated css that makes it centralized, but if i edit it in custom css, it's now working!]

Comment: try to change the id of input from inputName to inputEmail

Comment: it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: left` is applied to `control-label` therefore it overrides "center" applied to the parent element. Try using this css below

```
.control-label, .form-control {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS for the form:

```
.form-horizontal {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%; //Change it according to the design.
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/722/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the center tag, since you want the label to be centered.

```
<center>
  <div id="passCode"></div>

  <div class="container "> <!--center_div or center-block-->
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>


        <legend style="color:#145FAC">Please Fill in the Online Form</legend>


        <div class="form-group">

          <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control formWidth" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could apply this CSS to `form-control`:

```
text-align: center !important;
text-align: -webkit-center !important
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with a helper class .center-block. Try adding it to the label.

Answer (score 0):

I have added Bootply sample to you please check this it may works for you http://www.bootply.com/wokazmuDbv